# "give me five" and "slap me five", any difference?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, collocation

What's the meaning of "slap me five"? Any difference between "slap me five" and "give me five"?

There is a book called [*Slap Me Five*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000001ZGV).

Comment: I, for one, have never heard the phrase "slap me five".

Comment: I've never heard "slap me five" either, though it is fair to say that it means the same as "give me five" in this context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is only one of expression and context, not meaning. "Slap" me five is a funkier way of saying "give me five" or "give me some skin" or any of several ways of asking for a hand slap/slide.

Comment: Robusto's answer is correct.
These actions/expressions led to "high" fiving: same concept, but with hands held high instead of low.

Answer (score 1):

OK. You all must be too young! "Slap me five" was a term used in the 60s and 70s, when one person put their hand out in front of them and the other person slapped their hand. It was a gesture, like a greeting. A "cool" way of saying "hello." Probably more common in urban or inner city settings. "Slap me Five" and "Give me Five" meant the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Slap me five, 'gimmie five, and give me some skin were all synonymous greetings akin to a handshake, but with the palm up by the initiator.