# "slap yourself five"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Any ideas about what the "slap yourself five" means in the following context?

> "When someone says something you disagree with, before you call that person names and slap yourself five for your brilliant rebuttal, take a second to consider it fairly on its own terms."

Comment: For answerers, [the complete text is here](http://slatestarcodex.com/2014/05/23/ssc-gives-a-graduation-speech/). The author seems to be a native speaker.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6486/give-me-five-and-slap-me-five-any-difference

Answer (score 22):

To "give someone five" is to slap hands together in a congratulatory gesture.

Most often it is heard in the context of "gimme five" or "high five" (the act of slapping the palms together over the heads of the two participants). In this case, to "slap yourself five" would mean to congratulate yourself. Cf. "give yourself a pat on the back."

**Edit**:
See also: ["Give me five" and "slap me five": any difference?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/6486/2303)

Comment: That is the most likely interpretation, but I do see a few Google hits that imply something different.  It does not appear to be a common expression.

Comment: @Hot Licks, what's the other meaning(s)? +1, and gimme some skin, Robusto!

Comment: @LittleEva - The one I looked at halfway closely was some sort of mystical thing involving 5 slaps to yourself.

Comment: @Hot Licks - your kidding!

Comment: @LittleEva - I didn't look at it close enough to see if it was supposed to be serious, but it seemed so on the surface.  There are many things weirder on the Interweb.

Comment: @Hot Licks - I love that machine!

Comment: @Ginny: If this answer proved useful, you might consider clicking the arrow to accept it.

Comment: I have to admit that the first time I read the sentence I thought it was playing off the "give someone five", but was referring to a "face-palm" - slapping your hand to your forehead in a sign of *"DUH!, I made a stupid mistake."* The only reason I know I was wrong is because of the word "brilliant" in there.

Comment: I am sure that the author intended it this way (give congratulations to yourself), but to the OP it is not idiomatic English phrasing. One can 'slap oneself' (which sounds negative), but no one says 'slap five'... wait... UD describes that as something vulgar and so doing it to oneself is particularly vulgar. But congratulations to yourself! Chapeaux!

Answer (score -1):

the meaning of slap yourself 5 is very obscure.

A skilled English user would be able to tell that this is a mistranslation of "give yourself five", which is obscure, but means to smack your palms together above your head.

Comment: From the original text, the author seems to be a native speaker, so probably not translated. However, there are 'infelicities' in that full paragraph, leading me to believe that the author was not particularly careful and made mistakes, one of which was this.

Comment: I'm not convinced this was a mistake. It's certainly meaningful to *slap somebody else five*, meaning to high-five them. It's hardly a stretch from there to use this phrase as meaning to high-five yourself.

Comment: It is not a stretch, if admitting something you've never heard before among *thousands* of give me fives is part of the english cannon, is not a stretch

Comment: [Check this out, including the reference to the book title "Slap Me Five](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/6486/2303).

Comment: I stand corrected

Answer (score -5):

This is related a knee-slapper; one would slap their knee in response to something funny or in rare cases, frustration. In the example you gave it would be the latter.